# Not a Group By expression : Unclear on how to fix the issue

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am unsure of the main issue here and believe my code is correct but I do not know how to fix the issue provided being "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression".

```
SELECT distinct customer_city, customer_state, COUNT(*)
FROM customers
WHERE customer_state not in ('TX', 'OR')
GROUP BY ROLLUP(customer_state);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"distinct" is inappropriate for a group expression; your "group by" clause needs to include all non-grouped columns. Try this:

```
SELECT customer_city, customer_state, COUNT(*)
FROM customers
WHERE customer_state not in ('TX', 'OR')
GROUP BY ROLLUP (customer_city, customer_state);
```

Comment: Thank you @pmdba, appreciate the quick and explained response.

Answer (score 1):

The selected columns has to be part of the group by in ROLL UP as follows.

```
SELECT customer_city, customer_state, COUNT(*)
  FROM customers
 WHERE customer_state not in ('TX', 'OR')
GROUP BY ROLLUP(customer_city, customer_state);
```

Comment: Thank you @George Joseph for the help, fixed it with that adjustment.